# How to make foreign key inside models for particular column of composite primary key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

```
class1
{
    [key]
    public string id1 {get; set;}

    [Key]
    public string key2 {get; set;}
}

class2
{
    [foreignKey("class1")]
    public string class1Id{ get; set; }
}
```

Now here inside `class2` I want to use only `id1` column of `class1` as foreign key.

How to do that?

Comment: This doesn't seem related to ASP.NET.

Comment: You can't. The FK can point only to *unique* column in the referenced table (either primary or alternate key).

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer data annotations, just apply the ForeignKey attribute on the navigation property and provide a comma separated list with the FK property name

```
 class1{
    [key]
    public string id1 {get; set;}

    [Key]
    public string key2 {get; set;}
    }

    class2{

    public string id1 { get; set;}

    public string key2 { get; set;}

      [ForeignKey("id1,key2")] // <= the composite FK
      public virtual class1 class1{ get; set; }

    }
```

using fluent API configuration is much easier to understand and less error prone:

```
modelBuilder.Entity< class2>()
    .HasRequired(e => e. class1) 
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.id1, e.key2 });
```